# Update/Handle Active Directory user account using C# when ADFS 2.0 SSO is implemented

Tags: c#, active-directory, adfs2.0

Can I update/handle Active Directory user account using C# when ADFS 2.0 SSO is implemented?

Or once user get response from SSO i.e token/fault do I need to access Active Directory using LDAP connection for checking user status and badpassword-answer count?

Comment: Yes, you can, however you need to provide more details to get a more detailed answer.

Comment: I have internal user in my active directory. Once user enter username password and get response from STS. I want to check if user is disabled, locked and what is failedanswercount (extended property in our Active Directory). How can i implement that? It will be implemented in my web application? can i send response page url(of my web application where i will get those properties in some object) when i will get any pass/fail response from STS? And to acheive this whether STS can send me all details or I need to setup LDAP connection again to get disabled, locked, failedanswercount from my AD?

Comment: ADFS's login page is provided in a plain aspx/cs, at least in 2.0 which we use for years. The login page has a button click method that catches the exception. Although the exception doesn't provide any useful info, you can modify the cs file and add a custom logic. And yes, you need to do this manually, recreate the connection and ask with ldap protocol. The ADFS won't expose anything useful. We, for example, use a custom connection to host a pwd recovery page where users issue emails and then, when they come back from the link sent in an email, they are allowed to reset their own password.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. I also want to implement password recovery and account enabling functionality. When user is disabled/locked I want to send him/her to password recovery page. So how will be the flow here? Will it first go to STS for authentication (again this user in my AD) and then we can redirect to our password recovery page? or we can first check whether user is disabled or locked (assuming using seperate ldap connection) then first send to password recovery page and then else if user is active go to STS? What should be the flow please suggest.

Comment: Now we dont have SSO and password recovery. I want to implement both simultaneously. Currenly I am using regular ActiveDirectoryMemebershipProvider to getuser, validate user etc with my active directory.

Comment: The password recovery page in our solution is put on a separate app and the link is available on the ADFS login page. There is no auto redirect to the recovery page. It is just that when user logs in and sees the error message, he/she knows that the recovery page should be used. The system is used by 90k+ users and there are barely any issues with that.

Answer (score 1):

Once ADFS authenticates, you are into the token flow and redirect to RP and you don't get a chance to intercept so whatever custom code you want needs to come first.

Do all your AD stuff and then call the ADFS authentication.

**Warning:** ADFS 3,0 upwards does **NOT** use IIS so there is no upgrade path for this custom code.

**Update**:

in SubmitButton_Click in FormsSignIn:

Do your LDAP stuff then:

```
   try
   {
        SignIn( UsernameTextBox.Text, PasswordTextBox.Text );
   }


   catch ( AuthenticationFailedException ex )
   {
        // Check for lockout. password expired etc.
   }
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you please simplify this answer with steps? Exactly what i need to do first and where can i setup this configuration or when to call custom code? I am new to this.